# Eclipse Validation framework does not validate my XML files on-the-fly without xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xml-validation

On my Eclipse RCP product the Eclipse validation framework does not validate my XML files on-the-fly (while typing) or even while saving or manually invoking the validator by right-clicking on the file and selecting 'validate' option if there any syntax errors such as removing the end tag etc..
Here's what I have in my product's plugin.xml file -

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
      <content-type
            base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
            file-extensions="cst,xml"
            id="com.example.format.cst"
            name="CST"
            priority="normal">
         <describer class="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.RootXMLContentHandlerImpl$Describer">
            <parameter name="elementNames" value="CST"/>
         </describer>
      </content-type>
      <file-association 
            content-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
            file-extensions="cst">
      </file-association>
   </extension>
```

The validation framework works fine (shows syntax errors on-the-fly) if I have the xmlns namespace attribute in the XML file but the validation does not apply at all (does not show any errors) if the name space attribute 'xmlns' isn't present in my XML file, BTW the file extension for my XML file is CST.
Any suggestions or hint would be of great help!

Comment: You should make use a file-association, *or* define your own content-type, not both. What content type does your file identify as, with and without the namespace attribute? This is probably because of the `describer` class you've used.

Comment: The base content type is identified as xml and cst since the file extension is cst, I have defined my own content type anyways but how do I associate the file extension cst to it so that the Eclipse Validation Framework identifies these files as xml files and shows syntax errors if any? Can you please give an example?

Comment: As-you-type is a separate framework with its own extension point, since it adds information about which part of the document has changed during typing to the extensions. https://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/core/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui/schema/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation.exsd . Again, if you wanted certain behaviors to only apply to .cst files, then you want your own content type. Take a look at the XML entry on the content types preference page to get a better idea of when to use an association or a child content type. Again, not both.

Comment: I did not get much idea about how to get my 'cst' XML files validated by the Eclipse Validation framework, can you please throw some hints? I have defined my own content type but should I add a new extension point for org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2 and add my own validator class by extending org.eclipse.wst.validation.AbstractValidator class? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: The other uses of those extension points, in the same repository, are all working examples.

Comment: In that case should I be using any extension points for validators separately? should I be implementing the ISourceValidator class? The examples did not seem very clear to me or I may have misunderstood, any specific hints so that I can proceed further?

Comment: For a separate content type? Yes, you'll want to declare a source validator, even if it's for the same class used for the XML content type. Source Validation requires this in specifically because Ant and Maven pom files (possibly XSLT files as well) aren't expected to pass full XML validation. Syntactically they're the same, but they don't reference schemas and DTD files. This is why I've been trying understand if your files are merely using a custom filename extension, or are genuinely different and wouldn't pass validation as proper, well-formed XML.